# Render data passed from Django to Vue

Tags: django, vue.js, django-views

I get my data through axios with this:

```
get_questions: function (){
   axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
   axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken'
   axios.post('{% url 'sw_app:api_get_questions' %}', this.test)
      .then(response=>{
           this.questions = response.data.questions
           console.log(response.data.questions)
       })
}
```

Here's the view function:

```
def do_get_questions(request):

    data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    test_code = data['code']
    is_owner = check_test_owner(request, test_code)

    response = {}

    if is_owner:
        # Get Questions
        questions = models.Question.objects.filter(test__code=test_code)
        ser_questions = serializers.serialize('json', questions)

        response['result'] = 'ok'
        response['message'] = 'Questions fetched!'
        response['questions'] = ser_questions
        return JsonResponse(response)

    else:
        response['result'] = 'failed'
        response['message'] = 'You are not the owner of this test!'
        return JsonResponse(response)
```

It returns this:

```
[{"model": "sw_app.question", "pk": 2, "fields": {"test": 40, "content": "What is the phrase that beginner coders commonly use to display a string on the screen?"}}]
```

models.py for reference:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=900)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Question: {} - Test: {}".format(self.id, self.test.id)
```

Back in my vue (template), I store the questions here:

```
data: {
    test: {
        code: '',
    },
    questions: {}
},
```

Now when I do this:

```
<li class="list-group-item" v-for="question in questions" :key="question.pk">
    [[ question.content ]]
</li>
```

It just display a lot of empty list objects. When I try doing this:

```
<li class="list-group-item" v-for="question in questions" :key="question.pk">
    [[ question]]
</li>
```

It displays this:
[image: result from question]

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Because the question is an array now

Comment: @ArslanButt How can I display that?

Comment: How do you want to display?

Comment: As a list,, like `- question content here.... - another question.content here`

Comment: From this `[{"model": "sw_app.question", "pk": 2, "fields": {"test": 40, "content": "What is the phrase that beginner coders commonly use to display a string on the screen?"}}]`

Comment: See the answer I added code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have 2 questions so we can show them using `v-for`.

```js
    const app = new Vue({
     data() {
        return {
            test: {
            code: '',
        },
        questions: [{"model": "sw_app.question1",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
        "test": 40, "content": "Content for question 1"
        }
        },
        {"model": "sw_app.question2",
        "pk": 2,
        "fields": {
        "test": 40, "content": "Content for question 2"
        }
        }
        
        ],
        
        
        }
      },
  
    })
    app.$mount("#app")
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
      <div id="app">
      
     <li class="list-group-item" v-for="question in questions" :key="question.pk">
         {{ question.pk}} - {{ question.fields.content }} 
    </li> 

      </div>
```

Comment: It was how I send the data in my views.py that messed things up in Vue. But anyways, thanks for the help and the tip, I'll mark this one as the accepted answer to close the question.